# [UIView context]: unrecognized selector sent to instance after upgrade to Cocos2D-Swift v3.4.3

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, uikit

After upgrading an existing stable IOS app with the new version of the cocos2d library the app started crashing with the [UIView context]: unrecognized selector sent to instance error.

This typically occurs after CCDirector purgeCachedData is called.  Even after doing several things to reduce the memory resources used to almost half that being used by the app under the old cocos2d x3.0.0 alpha version.

The base of the app is using UIKit with cocos2d animation over the top of 4 different view controllers / uiviews.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!